# how to set global const variables in python

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, constants, declaration

I am building a solution with various classes and functions all of which need access to some global consants to be able to work appropriately. As there is no `const` in python, what would you consider best practice to set a kind of global consants.

```
global const g = 9.8
```

So I am looking for a kind of the above

edit: How about:

```
class Const():
    @staticmethod
    def gravity():
        return 9.8

print 'gravity: ', Const.gravity()
```

?

Comment: Doesn't work. Anyone can change `Const.gravity` or just replace the `Const` class entirely. The lack of anything like `const` is a deliberate design decision; Python makes it very difficult to enforce that code won't touch something it shouldn't. Instead, if you're not supposed to touch something, standard practice is to just not touch it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot define constants in Python. If you find some sort of hack to do it, you would just confuse everyone.

To do that sort of thing, usually you should just have a module - `globals.py` for example that you import everywhere that you need it

Comment: I suspected "As there is no const in python" :/

Comment: how do you name your consts? all caps? or something like c_gravitation?

Comment: PEP 8 says [all caps with underscores](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants).

Answer (score 11):

General convention is to define variables with capital and underscores and not change it. Like,

```
GRAVITY = 9.8
```

However, it is possible to create constants in Python using `namedtuple`

```
import collections

Const = collections.namedtuple('Const', 'gravity pi')
const = Const(9.8, 3.14)

print(const.gravity) # => 9.8
# try to change, it gives error
const.gravity = 9.0 # => AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

For `namedtuple`, refer to docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: This is the closest implementation of const..