# How to elegantly deal with global configuration in python package

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I am writing a package that needs some global constant variables. Although constant, these variables can be changed before doing anything else. For example, `nproc` is the number of processors used. Since allowing global variables to change is dangerous, these variables should be locked after the package is imported.

The only method I come up with is to read a configuration file. However, as a python package (not an application), it is really *weird* that a configuration file is needed.

What's the correct way to handle such global configuration?

**Edit**:

it is important to notice that these variables is not something like `pi` that will never change. It can be changed but should be constant during the usage of this package.

Comment: Why not use environment variables? If the environment variables are not set then perhaps use sensible defaults or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set global const variables in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224991/how-to-set-global-const-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is separating variables from source code then maybe I'd suggest [python-decouple](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple). I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class where the variables are set at initialisation time, and then use @property to declare a getter but not a setter.  For example:

```
# For Python 2, inherit from object
# (otherwise @property will not work)

class MyGlobals():

    # Possibly declare defaults here
    def __init__(self, nproc, var1, var2):
        self.__nproc = nproc
        self.__var1  = var1
        self.__var2  = var2

    @property
    def nproc(self):
        return self.__nproc

    @property
    def var1(self):
        return self.__var1

    @property
    def var2(self):
        return self.__var2



myg = MyGlobals(4, "hello", "goodbye")

print(myg.nproc, myg.var1, myg.var2)

myg.nproc = 42
```

Gives:

```
4 hello goodbye
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gash.py", line 29, in <module>
    myg.nproc = 42
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

The `MyGlobals` class would probably be placed in a module.

Comment: How do I set a default value?

Comment: Defaults could be set like this (example):  `def __init__(self, nproc=2, var1='hello', var2=None):`.