# How to initialize static variables in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I am trying to figure out a way of declaring a variable whose value can not be changed in any way (static in c++),  but in python3. Please let me know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: IIRC this is not what "static" means in c++. Sounds like what you're looking for is something similar to Java's `final` keyword. AFAIK there is no such thing in Python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set global const variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224991/how-to-set-global-const-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

there is no way of creating a const variable in python3, but there are some option and recommendation too, 
check the link below-
[how to set global const variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224991/how-to-set-global-const-variables-in-python)